# Why Proguard doesn't make change in my code?

Tags: android, proguard

I want to obfuscate and reduce size of my project but after change the 'minifyEnabled' and 'shrinkResources' to true nothing changes.
What should i do?
Thanks

```
    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the `release` build type?

Comment: and proguard will change the apk, not your project or your code

Comment: how you know obfuscation is not done in your apk?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes

Comment: @JolsonDaCosta By checking APK size and decompiling that.

Comment: can you add your proguard rules

Comment: @ManoharReddy Yes

Comment: @AliRahbari obfuscation and Shrinking are two different things . shrinking is easy to understand and depends on resource and unused files. obfuscation not working could have many reason . one could be you using reflection in your code or rules you specified

Answer (score -1):

I'm using like this, and don't forget to add all libraries proguard if they have. If you don't, you may have an error after running your signed app.
My proguard just an example. You need to find proguard of your libraries and add them to proguard file.

```
 buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false // shrink
                useProguard false   // don't obfuscate when set to FALSE

                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

            release {
                minifyEnabled true  // shrink
                useProguard true // obfuscate

                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }


//proguard need to be like this...
# Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
    -keep class com.engloshidiomsgrammarapp.speakfluentenglish.model.**{ *; }
```

Comment: Same as past still no changes.

Comment: how did you check it? if you dont sign your apk you can not see any changes. When you debug your app, it's not using proguard. So it will not change. Only if you sign your apk and get apk from your release folder you can see changes.

Comment: Yes thats right @VedprakashWagh . because of that nothing changes when the app is debugged. Because proguard is ignored.

Comment: The problem is solved it caused by no sign APK .thanks for your guide